# Execute CURL with kubectl

Tags: azure, curl, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to execute `curl` command with `kubectl` like

```
kubectl exec POD_NAME "curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/abc -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{\"name\":\"aaa\",\"no\":\"10\"}' "
```

Gives belob error

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"kubectl exec POD_NAME "curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/abc -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{\"name\":\"aaa\",\"no\":\"10\"}'\": 
stat kubectl exec POD_NAME "curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/abc -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{\"name\":\"aaa\",\"no\":\"10\"}' ": no such file or directory" 
:unknown command terminated with exit code 126
```

I have tried to escape the quotes but no luck. Then I tried simple curl

```
kubectl exec -it POD_NAME curl http://localhost:8080/xyz
```

This gives proper output as excepted. Any help with this

Update:

But when I run interactive (`kubectl exec -it POD_NAME /bin/bash`) mode of container and then run the curl inside the container works like champ

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to do something like this:

```
kubectl exec POD_NAME curl "-X PUT http://localhost:8080/abc -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{\"name\":\"aaa\",\"no\":\"10\"}' "
```

what the error suggests is that its trying to interpret everything inside `""` as a single command, not as a command with parameters. so its essentially looking for an executable called that

Comment: For exactly that reason you don't need to put any quotes there `kubectl exec POD_NAME -- curl .....`. Otherwise the whole quote delimited string would be treated as a single argument.

Comment: i think it depends on the shell you are using, I'm using powershell so `--` doesnt work for me

Comment: In powershell `"` also denotes a **single** string literal, hence a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me in Centos. But with windows it won't work.

> kubectl -n elk exec -it eai-lf-elasticsearch-0 -- curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/testsnapfromcurl?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type": "fs","settings": {"location": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/backups/testsnapfromcurl"}}'
> Defaulting container name to elasticsearch.
> Use 'kubectl describe pod/elasticsearch-0 -n elk' to see all of the containers in this pod.
> {
> "acknowledged" : true
> }

Answer (score 0):

It's works fine in win machine from bash console:
kubectl exec POD_ID -- curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/testsnapfromcurl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name":"aaa","no":"10"}'"

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl exec -n NAMESPACE -c CONTAINER PODNAME curl "URL"
```